# Passing variable to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in a spreadsheet but the marco needs you to input some text. I ran to run this and auto fill the text

I read the MS page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run

and tried other steps but I can't get it working

When I run the CreatePartner I want to pass the text like "TATA" so that when the marco is executed and asks for the customer name TATA is automatically input.

As is I get the error Object required: '[string: "Tata"]

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\excelvbs\MPR-TEMPLATE-partner.xlsx")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\excelvbs\KSDW-DataOnly-Customer_Partner.xlsm")
    Set rCustomer = "Tata"

vResult = objExcel.Application.Run ("CreatePartner", rCustomer)
```

Comment: What did your search of the documentation for `Application.Run` turn up? Your question can be answered in about 15 seconds with Google. Please don't post Stack Overflow questions as a substitute for a search engine. Ask questions when reasonable efforts at research fails.

Comment: For further info you can also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I did look it up but I am having trouble getting the macro arguments to work. what does it mean arguments have to be passed by position?

Comment: @Brendan That is a very different question. The question wouldn't have been closed if you discussed how you tried to pass the parameters and the nature of the trouble that you ran into. The question as written is a general question whose answer can be easily found in the documentation. Perhaps you can edit your question so that it is more specific to your particular problem. If so, I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have done so.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but why are you using `Set` to assign a string value to a variable? That error seems unrelated to your question.

Comment: Was just testing some different things.

Comment: Once you eliminate `Set` from that line, the assignment should go through (unless there is a type mismatch). The line `vResult = objExcel.Application.Run ("CreatePartner", rCustomer)` looks fine -- but we have no idea what `CreatePartner` is and how it should be called. If it is not a function which is expecting a single string variable as input, it could fail. It would help if this were more of a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks John. CreatePartner is the name of the Macro and when the macro is executed it has a popup asking for information. I am trying to pass "TATA" to this macro. I am getting an error about Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: How is `CreatePartner` *defined*? What is the very first line of its definition? It should be something along the lines of `Function CreatePartner(s As String) As Variant`. Without any idea of what sort of input that function is expecting, it is impossible to say why your use of `Application.Run` is failing.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman CreatePartner is actually an embedded macro in the sheet KSDW-DataOnly-Customer_Partner.. If I change it to vResult = objExcel.Application.Run ("CreatePartner") it works but I get prompted to enter information. I want this to be done automatically.

Comment: That is simply impossible. `Application.Run` won't feed the parameters you pass it to a popup. Refactor the code so that `CreatePartner` is expecting a passed parameter rather than input from an inputbox. If need be, create a different version of the function, e.g. `CreatePartner2(s As String)`

Comment: @JohnColeman Ahh ok so you are saying change the macro itself. Mostly around here: client = InputBox("Enter the name of the Company", "Company Name")

Comment: Yes. I don't see any shortcut if you want to use `Application.Run` (but why use that at all rather than simply *call* the function?). You seem to have a somewhat vague notion of basic VBA (or is this really VBScript?) semantics. It might not hurt to read a book or tutorial.

Comment: @JohnColeman I will do some reading. I am vague yes. Any chance you can show me an example of how you would do this?

Comment: @JohnColeman Think I got it thanks for your advice. This is way easier than i thought I think